# Add button to Django admin index page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, url-routing

I want to add a site-wide action to Django admin, called "Synchronize SQL-KB".
[image: Site-wide button "Synchronize SQL-KB"]

For that I have copied locally `templates/admin/index.html` file from Django and modified it as follows:

```
...
{% if app_list %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="sync-sql-kb/">Synchronize SQL-KB</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% for app in app_list %}
    ...
```

So as you can see I want the link button to trigger a request to `/admin/sync-sql-kb/`.

How to register this URL now? Where and how to implement a handler function?

Note that this situation in my view differs from other SO questions in that the action is site-wide, rather than bound to a specific Django model.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own views & just register them alongside the admin URLs;

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/sync-sql-kb/', myapp.urls),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then you could just do; `<a href="/admin/sync-sql-kb/">Synchronize SQL-KB</a>`

Ensure your view does the correct checking for the user being staff or superuser, depending on what you need. Also consider that you can name your URLs and use `reverse` as normal for this.

I would recommend adding your link to the `userlinks` block of the admin templates as well. Read this for more information; https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django/admin.html#customize-top-right-corner-of-admin-pages